# Monotouch.Dialog: BooleanElement's ValueChanged event is not firing

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Is there a special trick required to get `BooleanElement's` `ValueChanged` event firing?
The code below is never executed if I switch the status:

```
this.oElementSenderCC = new BooleanElement ("Send Copy To Myself" ), true);
this.oElementSenderCC.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => this.SelectedSenderCC = this.oElementSenderCC.Value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems working for me

```
BooleanElement boolElm = new BooleanElement("Bool",false);
boolElm.ValueChanged+=delegate
{ Console.WriteLine(boolElm.Value); };
```

Comment: Agreed, it works for me too, using the original syntax (minus the typo).

Comment: Hm, you're initializing with FALSE. I have TRUE. Could that be the reason? What version of Monotouch are you using? I'm on 5.2.6.

Comment: I double checked. It is really working now. But I upgraded my MT version meanwhile. No idea but at least it's all good now.